# Take 1st Letter of words in excel to make a concat SKU

Tags: excel, formula

I have about 300 products i've purchased i need to setup SKU's for, I can do this manually but i'd like to us some simple code to do it if possible. I'd like to append the letters to ANC.

i.e Small Bite collar & lead set Chocolate heart - ANC_SBC&SCH
30cm/12" Nylon Dog Collar Blk - ANC_3NDCB

Comment: Are you not concerned about ending up with non uniques?

Comment: I will let you know that most people are not going to just write the code for you. This is a code helping site not a services site. If you have some code that is not working then other user will be more willing to assist.

Comment: Why? just use an sequence number.  less headache in the long run. No chance at dups this way and if the name changes and trust me they do, you keep the same number.

Comment: I agree with @xQbert from a domain perspective. Best to use a more generic SKU. If you require that ability to identify a product based on its SKU, suggest doing it categorically. DC0001...DC00123 (Dog Collar) FB0001...FB0010 (Food Bowl) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **UDF**

```
Public Function sku(s As String) As String
    ary = Split(s, " ")
    For Each a In ary
        sku = sku & Left(a, 1)
    Next a
    sku = "ANC_" & sku
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula version:

```
="ANC_"&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)
```